# useCallback inline function styles

Tags: reactjs

What's the difference:

1st example:

```
const onClose = useCallback(onModalClose, []);
```

2nd example:

```
const onClose = useCallback(() => onModalClose, []);
```

onModalClose call as component prop:

```
<CustomComponent
  onModalClose={() => setDeleteModal(false)}
/>
```

When using a 2nd example, linter would yell on me, because deps array is empty, `onModalClose` should be in a deps array, that causing issues with multiple re-renders. Using a 1st example causes no issues with re-renders and doesn't require a deps array.

Comment: Just to get the context of your question. What are you trying to achieve by wrapping the ```onModalClose``` in ```useCallback``` hook, then at the end you still pass ```onModalClose``` as a ```prop```  to ```CustomComponent```

Comment: did u mean `onModalClose={() => onClose(false)}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you mean `const onClose = useCallback(() => onModalClose(), []);` in your second example, the only significant difference is the second is wrapped in an inline function.

`useCallback` takes a function to memoize, that is its signature. Without knowing anything about the function `onModalClose` the linter has nothing to complain about in the first example since you're directly memoizing the function as a callback. In the second you are declaring an anonymous function that calls another function. It is *this* function call the linter sees and suggests adding *it* to the dependency array.

Depending on where `onModalClose` is defined you may be able to safely add it to the dependency array (i.e. if it is defined *outside* the functional component then its reference is ***stable*** and won't change between renders), or you can leave the dependency array empty and may need to add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to the line above it so the linter stops "yelling at you".

```
const onClose = useCallback(onModalClose, []);
```

or

```
const onClose = useCallback(
  () => onModalClose(),
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  [],
);
```

Between the two I'd prefer the first as it's perfectly clear you're memoizing the function callback *and* requires less text (i.e. no need to provide an eslint override.